# mkdir() or chmod() set directories contents to hidden, but subdirectories contents to viewable

Tags: php, chmod, mkdir

I'm creating a file-based storage system for small indie game developers to use with their games. It's all controlled by a single PHP file, that handles 'queries' via POST / GET variables. I want the PHP file to create a directory that holds sub-directories (one for each game). I dont want anyone to view the games within this main directory, so they cant view other games IDs, but if they have their games ID, they can view the contents of their games folder.

Here's the main directory that holds the game directories:
http://shadespeed.com/shadetech_storage/

I want to hide all of the contents within that folder, but show contents within the sub-directories, such as this:
http://shadespeed.com/shadetech_storage/12345678/

Is this possible?

Looking at chmod(), I can't find any modes that do what I want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Many thanks,

- Dan.

Comment: perhaps use a recursive function? even though I don't think it's the best way to do it..

Comment: I think i've temporarily fixed it, by adding an html file (index.html) to the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've used  workaround. I simply created an HTML file (index.html) in the main directory. It works for now, but I'm not sure if it will stop people who know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should simple create `.htaccess` file with content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

You can simple put it in main folder when you don't want users to display files in this directory so in your case probably in directory `http://shadespeed.com/shadetech_storage/`

Answer (score 0):

If your server is Apache based, simply use an `.htaccess` file in the main directory that forbids access to that directory content (as in Code 1), and `.htaccess` files in each subdirectory in order to allow access to them (as in Code 2)

Code 1:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Code 2:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```